# asp.net 4.5 MVC SQL using distinct

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, distinct

```
@foreach (var item in Model) { string mytown = item.town.*enter distinct here* <option value="@mytown"> @mytown</option>
```

This selects all the town names in my database and I've got it to display in a drop down menu.

How can I change this so that when it's displaying the town names, it will only show each town name once.

For example, if I have 3 londons in the database it will show all 3 londons in the drop down menu. I want it to only show 1 london

FYI: Sorry this may seem like a repost but I posted the wrong code earlier

Comment: Its a repost.. but it doesn't change the answer from your previous question. Use `Distinct`.

Comment: You should do that in the controller.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead My apologies

Answer (score 2):

```
myCollection.Select(x => x.Name).Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as my understanding, you can't do this if you are using ID as value.

Say

```
ID | Value
1    Landon
2    Landon
3    Landon
4    Los Angeles
```

Better way you can achieve this is by using LINQ. Get the list from the database then filter it in the controller `towns.Where(x => x.Name == x.Name.Distinct());`

further
Inside controller action

```
ViewBag.towns = new SelectList(towns.Where(x => x.Name == x.Name.Distinct()).ToList(), "Value", "Text");
```

Inside view

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedTown, new SelectList(ViewBag.towns, "ID", "Name", Model.SelectedTown))
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not convert it to a `HashSet<string>()`?

```
var hs = new HashSet<string>(Model);
```

given, `Model` is `IEnumerable<string>` ?

Or, do that in the controller, by converting the `List<T>` to `HashSet<T>` and then pass it as an `IEnumerable<T>` to the model.

or this one:

`from y in Model.Distinct() select y`